# Can't extend Keycloak.v2 theme's AccountPage.js

Tags: keycloak

I was following the Keycloak documentation on adding custom user attributes:
https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/#_custom_user_attributes

I successfully updated the registration form to collect new attributes. I then went on to update the account page, but noticed I had been using the keycloak.v2 theme, so thought I would try extending that instead.

I know my theme is being applied correctly, because I used the theme.properties to set a new logo and favicon and they are appearing correctly:

```
parent=keycloak.v2
logo=/public/my-logo.svg
logoUrl=./
favIcon=/public/my-icon.ico
```

However, none of the changes I make to extend the AccountPage.js file seem to be taking effect.

My simple test change:

First I copied the existing AccountPage.js file in the keycloak.v2 folder and placed it in my theme in the same location:

```
/home/ubuntu/keycloak/keycloak-15.0.2/themes/keycloak.v2/account/resources/content/account-page/AccountPage.js
/home/ubuntu/keycloak/keycloak-15.0.2/themes/mytheme    /account/resources/content/account-page/AccountPage.js
```

Then all I did was change the last name label in the file:

from:

```
  label: Msg.localize('lastName'),
```

to:

```
  label: "Laaaaaast Name",
```

and after turning off the caches, and restarting the server and reloading the page in a fresh browser I still see "Last Name" next to the last name input.

I feel like I'm misunderstanding something about the way keycloak layers the files when extending.

**What do I need to do in order to see updates I make to the AccountPage.js?**

Comment: Hi, did you find any solution for it?

Comment: @SyedSaeedulHassanAli This project has been deprioritized, So i haven't looked at it since. If I figure this out in the future, I'll be sure to provide an answer.

Answer (score 0):

From what I see, you did the right steps, however you didn't mention if you have changed the theme in realm settings, so I would check there:

Select a realm -> Go to '**Realm settings**' -> **Themes** tab and select 'mytheme' as **account theme**.
Save and verify if you see the changes.